# How can I add salt and get it to permeate throughout chocolate?

Tags: chocolate, salt

Based on a previous question I understand it is not possible to make chocolate from home since specialist and expensive equipment is reqiured.  As such I bought premade dark chocolate from the shop, melted it(brang water pot to simmer, added anotther pot wih chocolate in to top of first pot). I then added salt in as I wanted to increase the salt content of the chocolate ensuring the salt is distributed well.

When eating the chocolate I noticed that the salt did not distribute throughout the chocolate and the grains didnt even dissolve properly. large salt grains were present in the chocolate.

I then melted some coconut butter in the same way, added salt and noticed the salt grains didnt dissolve either so clearly need to do more to get the salt to dissolve and distribute.  I added water to the coconut butter and it the salt did dissolve however it seemed to still be seperate from the coconut fat in the same way oil seperates from water.  I then added coco powder.  When I ate it although the salt grains did dissolve it still seems not to have distributed/penetrated the chocolate well.

Chocolate bars with a high salt content e.g. twirl, flake have the result i'm looking for i.e salt is distributed well throughout.  Anyone know how i can get premade chocolate, add salt and get it to distribute like the aforementioned bars, or cook from scratch getting the salt to distribute properly?  I cant just use the aforementioned premade bars because they have many other ingredients which I'm trying to avoid.

-- UPDATE --

I have just noticed that the chocolate bars I have been comparing to e.g. twirl, flake do not have salt added as an ingredient.  However they still have 0.25g of salt per 100g of chocolate.  I guess it means its naturally occuring as a result of one of the ingredients or managing to merge that ingredient with the other ingredient hence getting the seemingly well distriuted salt.  Does anyone know which ingredient gives it the salt(I'd guess milk).  If I wanted to then emulate the recipe would I simply melt chocolate as previously and then add milk, is there some possible way to make the salt distribution like aformentioned store bought chocolates now that I know it definately wasnt as a result of adding/cooking salt?

Comment: You should be able to get it pretty evenly distributed even if it doesn't dissolve completely, and it's just going to dissolve when you eat it anyway. Is dissolving a requirement? Is it just that you don't like the texture you got? Or that you were getting really salty bites? There are also alternatives like putting an even sprinkle of salt over the top, but I'm not sure what would be acceptable for you.

Comment: There is unlikely enough water in the chocolate to dissolve the salt. Salt is not at all soluble in fats and is ionic enough to actually cause phase separation in foods sometimes. All the salted chocolates I have had seemed to have discernible salt crystals, on the large side and definitely not dissolved. Can you not blend them into molten chocolate using a slow speed blender or do it by hand? You need to maintain the chocolate at the right temperature over a water bath while blending. There should be enough viscosity and density to keep the crystals suspended.

Comment: If you do not want crystals, I think it might not be achievable at home without a conche, just like sweetening chocolate with sugar, no matter how fine a salt/sugar powder you have, and you are unlikely to get really dust fine powders in a home kitchen either.

Comment: Flake and twirl bars do not list salt as an ingredient.

Comment: @Jefromi I wondered if maybe they do in the US (I'm in the UK and they don't here). But I see you're that side of the Atlantic.

Comment: @ChrisH I just googled (I don't have a bar in front of me), and I believe I saw UK ones ("flavour" etc). But the OP is in the UK too.

Comment: @Jefromi thanks for noticing that, however I notice the choclate still contains 0.25g of salt per 100g of chocolate.  It must be naturally occuring.  Perhaps if I knew how they do that I'd know whether I can reproduce at home.

Comment: Perhaps UK labeling allows salt to be listed as "flavour" rather than an ingredient in its own right? I don't think that .25g/100g is natural in cocoa. It's also a really small amount, though, something like 1/20 of a teaspoon, something that you could even just sprinkle over the top of chocolate and hardly have enough grains to worry about.

Comment: @Jefromi, no, salt is always listed explicitly. But the salt probably comes from the milk. One of the reasons cows' milk isn't given to babies is that it's too salty for them.

Comment: But now I wonder what happens to all the water in the milk when they make chocolate (dried milk or milk fat would be listed as such normally).

Comment: I don't see where the OP says UK (but metric units point to non-US). The use of "brang" is rare in most of the UK, but I've heard it in American use.

Comment: I thought it was usually milk solids, but I've seen labels that just say "milk" as well as ones that say "milk solids". Anyway, if that's enough to account for the salt, sounds like the OP could try dry milk (milk powder) or just find a brand of milk chocolate he likes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. Salt is water-soluble, and chocolate is made out of starch suspended in fat, without water. You cannot dissolve the salt in the fat.

Adding small amounts of a liquid in which the salt is dissolved will also not help, as it will curdle the chocolate. At least it will certainly happen with water. <strike>Alcohol can have some chance of working, as it dissolves both polar and nonpolar compounds, but you will need pure (96% medical) ethanol, not an alcoholic drink. I think this is quite impractical even if it works, but you may want to experiment with it.</strike> A commenter who has tried it notes that not even alcohol will work.

The closest you could do at home is to make a ganache with either cream (standard) or water, and dissolve the salt in the water phase before making it. The least amount you can have is 20% water (if using cream or another liquid, you have to adjust for its solid content so you end up with 20% water in total). This will give you a creamy ganache, and quite concentrated, but not a chocolate bar.

The only other thing I can think of is to go the way you already did - retemper chocolate and adding salt while melted - but you will not have it dissolve. What you can change is to grind it into a fine powder first, so you don't feel the grains as much. But it will still be grains suspended in the chocolate, not salt dissolved throughout the chocolate.

Comment: Alcohol is also polar enough to do mess up the chocolate. I have tried that many times (to sweeten 100% chocolate) and ended up very disappointed without exception. Even anhydrous ethanol did not work.I agree that making a ganache is the only way out which can always be coated with tempered chocolate.

Comment: @rumtscho I guess you are saying that premade chocolate bars also do not have the salt distributed throughout.  Rather the salt and chocolate is grinded down so finely that it appears as though the salt has distrubuted those chocolate bars?

Comment: @JamesWilson I have never had a premade chocolate bar with salt distributed through it. The only salted chocolate I've seen simply had fleur de sel flakes spread on top.

Comment: I'd assume that given that conching gets the cocoa solids ground so finely that we perceive it as a smooth bar of chocolate (even though they're not dissolved), the same could in principle be done for salt - but I'm not sure if I've ever seen it. I looked at ingredient lists for a few mass-market chocolate bars just now, including the ones the OP mentioned, and they don't list salt as an ingredient.

Comment: Same experience. Always distinct crystals of salt scattered throughout the chocolate. There is a Lindt Excellence Sea Salt bar that comes to mind, not sure if it is 55% or 65% solids.

Comment: According to https://www.blackmountainchocolate.com/blogs/craftingchocolate/11775333-reason-12-the-daily-grind, conched chocolate is on the order of 20 microns. Regular salt is about 100 microns; Morton extra fine is 44. There was talk of a 15-micron salt being used on Lay's potato chips (for full salt flavor with less salt), but I don't know what became of that.

Comment: Popcorn salt is really fine, don't know how fine, but should be easily less than half the size of regular salt, and I wouldn't be surprised if it were smaller than the conched chocolate. So it seems totally possible to get it small enough to evenly distribute without noticing grains. (No, it wouldn't be *dissolved*, but that doesn't mean it's not distributed throughout.)

Comment: Exactly my thoughts: Use finely ground salt. If you can't get finely enough ground salt, YOU grind it finer!

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments on the question, it sounds like the salt level of the "high salt content" commercial chocolate is not particularly high, and possibly just from the milk. So it might be possible to find a different brand of milk chocolate without the undesired ingredients.

If you're really set on modifying your own chocolate, starting with popcorn salt might make it small enough that you don't notice any grains. It's basically powdered salt. Just make sure that you get plain salt, not some flavored variety for popcorn. This is not too much different from rumtscho's suggestion of grinding the salt, just maybe a little easier.

There also seems to be some misunderstanding about grains vs "distributed throughout" vs dissolving. If you have fine enough grains evenly mixed in, then it *is* distributed throughout. Sure, it won't be dissolved, but that doesn't mean you're going to notice any grains or unevenness. The cocoa solids aren't dissolved in chocolate either, but it seems perfectly smooth and evenly distributed all the same.

Note that unless you take pains to keep the chocolate tempered or retemper it, the resulting chocolate after melting and resolidifying will not have the same snap and shine as the original chocolate.